# Failing to query Input

Tags: javascript

Hey im creating a dynamic modal with an input field and a button. Upon clicking the button an event fires and creates a list with the data which was inserted into the input field. The problem is that i always get the message that the input is empty. Here is my Code.

The modal:

```js
function listModal() {
  var modalElement = document.createElement("div");
  var headerElement = document.createElement("div");
  var titleElement = document.createElement("div");
  var bodyElement = document.createElement("div");

  var closeButtonElement = document.createElement("button");
  var inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  var buttonElement = document.createElement("button");

  modalElement.className = "modal listModal";
  modalElement.classList.add("active");
  headerElement.className = "modal-header";
  titleElement.className = "title";
  bodyElement.className = "modal-body";
  closeButtonElement.className = "close-button"
  buttonElement.className = "listButton";

  titleElement.innerHTML = "Create new List";
  inputElement.placeholder = "New-List..."
  buttonElement.innerHTML = "Add List";


  headerElement.appendChild(titleElement);
  headerElement.appendChild(closeButtonElement);

  bodyElement.appendChild(inputElement);

  modalElement.appendChild(headerElement);
  modalElement.appendChild(bodyElement);
  modalElement.appendChild(buttonElement);

  document.body.appendChild(modalElement);


}


if (ev.target.className === "createListBar") {
  listModal();
}
false;
})

//Create list
document.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {

  if (ev.target.className === "listButton") {

    var target = event.target;
    var modal = target.parentElement;
    var input = modal.querySelector("input");

    var inputValue = input.value;

    if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
      createList(inputValue);
      modal.classList.remove('active');

    }
    input.value = "";

  }

})
```

I am not really sure whats wrong, since i wrote most of my code in the html file, but since i wanted to create a file only for js code the code does not work anymore.

Thank you for your help. 
An extra question, if it is ok to ask: Since i have some extra time i looked for an online webdesign and javascript course, if you have any suggestions i would be glad to try them out.

Comment: Please, see the errors in console and fix it.You have 5 lines of code wondering around. Actually, create a [mcve] - it's hard to comprehend what elements you have in the DOM

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I read the article and found my fault as well. Somehow another part of my code created another modal which overlapped the one which I queried

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass in *ev* as the event object, but use *event* in the function. You should stick to either *ev* or *event*. Like this for example:

```
//Create list
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  if (event.target.className === "listButton") {

    var target = event.target;
    var modal = target.parentElement;
    var input = modal.querySelector("input");

    var inputValue = input.value;

    if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
      createList(inputValue);
      modal.classList.remove('active');

    }
    input.value = "";

  }

})
```